# Как контролировать толщину символа?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt, qss

Я не знаю в чем дело но когда я использую `font-weight` то кроме значений между 487 и 488 я нечего не нахожу еще я нашел очень толстую обводку между 9999 и 100000000000.
В интернете я нашел только setWeightно он не работает.
Я бы хотел нормально и точно контролировать толщину символов. Но не знаю что для этого нужно делать.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.setStyleSheet('background: red;')        
        
        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        lay.setSpacing(0)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        
        label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label_1.setText("1")
        label_1.setStyleSheet('font-size: 200px;font-weight:488;')
        label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(label_1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label_2.setText("1")
        label_2.setStyleSheet('background:#00000000; font-size: 200px; color:blue;font-weight:487;')
        label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(label_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Update

Я сделал 10 `labels` и увиличил толщену каждого на `100`
Но плавность я так и не получил.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.setStyleSheet('background: black;')        
        
        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        lay.setSpacing(0)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        
        label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label_1.setText("1")
        label_1.setStyleSheet('font-size: 200px;font-weight:900;')
        label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(label_1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label_2.setText("1")
        label_2.setStyleSheet('background:#00000000; font-size: 200px; color:pink;font-weight:800;')
        label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(label_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label_3.setText("1")
        label_3.setStyleSheet('background:#00000000; font-size: 200px; color:purple;font-weight:700;')
        label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(label_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label_4.setText("1")
        label_4.setStyleSheet('background:#00000000; font-size: 200px; color:blue;font-weight:600;')
        label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(label_4, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label_5.setText("1")
        label_5.setStyleSheet('background:#00000000; font-size: 200px; color:green;font-weight:500;')
        label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(label_5, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label_6.setText("1")
        label_6.setStyleSheet('background:#00000000; font-size: 200px; color:yellow;font-weight:400;')
        label_6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(label_6, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label_7.setText("1")
        label_7.setStyleSheet('background:#00000000; font-size: 200px; color:orange;font-weight:300;')
        label_7.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(label_7, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label_8.setText("1")
        label_8.setStyleSheet('background:#00000000; font-size: 200px; color:red;font-weight:200;')
        label_8.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(label_8, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label_9.setText("1")
        label_9.setStyleSheet('background:#00000000; font-size: 200px; color:brown;font-weight:100;')
        label_9.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(label_9, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label_10.setText("1")
        label_10.setStyleSheet('background:#00000000; font-size: 200px; color:white;font-weight:0;')
        label_10.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(label_10, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код верен, нужно только следить за значением `font-weight`. Оно лежит в промежутке от 100 до 900 включительно, и обязательно должно быть кратно 100 (то есть можно использовать `100`, `200`, `300`, ..., `900`).

Скриншот, показывающий разницу между минимальным (`100`) и максимальным (`900`) значениями `font-weight`:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Если `font-weight` принимает только значения кратные `100` то тогда зачем вообще нужны лишние `00`? 
И можно ли контролировать толщину более плавно?

Comment: @orlatym это уже к `CSS` вопросы. Часть шрифтов вообще могут только 3 значения ширины принимать.

Comment: А есть ли другой способ менять ширину шрифта? Ну или сделать обводку буквы. Так что бы я мог это более плавно это контролировать